# Binder transaction failing in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-binder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed Binder Transaction when returning camera image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264980/failed-binder-transaction-when-returning-camera-image)

What are the chances of binder transaction failing in android stack? I have an application which switches thru different activities, but the size of data being exchanged between each activity is very less (less than 20 bytes) which includes no images. In some case, system crashes out with out of memory and in other cases application terminates.

Please help...I am in a real spot of bother..

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are over-logging. Or that there is a huge memory leak. 
Minimize your application and run the android Task Manager. Depending on your android (mobile) device you can cause the system to crash if there is over-logging or big leaks.

Comment: Thanks...Is there any tool available in Android which can find memory leak...?

Comment: [This blog was useful](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html). There are lot of questions asked here on SO about this. [Use this query ?](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=memory+leaks+android+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Reduced logging to a large extent and I guess it did help

Answer (score 3):

During a remote procedure call, the arguments and the return value of the call are transferred as Parcel objects stored in the Binder transaction buffer. If the arguments or the return value are too large to fit in the transaction buffer, then the call will fail and TransactionTooLargeException will be thrown.

refer this link form  [android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)