# How to change Cordova camera plugin options

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using cordova camera plugin. It works fine. But i have two problems. One of them; after i capture photo  2 buttons appear. Their names are "Save" and "Discard". I want to rename them with "confirm" and "Cancel". How can i do this? an other question; after Saving photo, my photo is turning. How can i block this?

Answer (score 2):

1. Save/Discard - you can't do this in the Cordova Camera API presented to you.
   You'd need to write your own plugin which uses a `SurfaceView` (more
   detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297606/android-take-camera-picture-without-save-delete-confirmation)).
2. This is a known Android issue - it ignores the `correctOrientation` parameter - I believe however that it uploads the photo in the correct orientation. It just is not shown correctly.

Comment: for 2. i checked my uploads file. it did not upload the photo in the correct orientation. can i fix it?

Comment: @keidar Thanx for the SurfaceView link. But how exactly is this implemented? Just getting to know android and cordova.

Answer (score 1):

after i add correctOrientation in my code, it shown phooto correctly.

navigator.camera.getPicture(photoCaptured,photoCapturedFail,
{
   quality: 50,
   destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   **correctOrientation: true**
});