# Can we bypass save and delete option in intent camera for taking image in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to by pass save and delete option on taking image from Android Intent Camera, without using custom camera. Save image directly just capturing image.

Comment: Try This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297606/android-take-camera-picture-without-save-delete-confirmation

Comment: I don't want to use custom camera. I had to use Intent Camera only for this.

Comment: it is only the workaround'

Comment: Thanks Amy but I had to intent camera for this if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a "quick capture" mode in Android stock camera, at least in Android 5.0 and 5.1, it works as intended on Nexus but does not work on my Samsung phone, because of custom Samsung camera app. Also I'm not sure it will work on older versions of Android.

Test it from ADB shell:

`adb shell am start -a android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE --ez android.intent.extra.quickCapture 1`

And Java code would be something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true);
```

Comment: This is one of the vulnerabilities that have been [recently sealed](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2019/11/google-samsung-fix-android-spying-flaw-other-makers-may-still-be-vulnerable/), isn't it?

Comment: Looks like it might be that vulnerability. Intent name is different though, and user still must press the shutter button, so the only way to know if this API still works is to test it on Pixel.

Comment: Right, this is a different **extra**, and you are right, *per se* it's not a vulnerability. Thanks!