# Back button not working after taking picture

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to implement a solution that I found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297606/android-take-camera-picture-without-save-delete-confirmation)
but after I hit capture, the back button doesn't finish the activity. Is there a way to call

```
finish();
```

when the back button is pressed within the function

```
private void capture() {
    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        final float bearing = degree;

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            latitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLatitude();
            longitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Taken",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" +
                    latitude + ", " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + bearing, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("image_arr", data);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            camera.stopPreview();
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();  
    finish();
}
```

Comment: what app shows after capture ??

Comment: It just displays the captured image within the view

Comment: did u tryed to override the backbuttonPressed method ??

Comment: I override that function outside the function. I edited the question to include that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok instead of doying `finish();` try to make an intent to the desired `activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity, DesiredActivity));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: That worked! Do you happen to know why the regular back button wasn't working? I'm just curious

Comment: sorry i don't have an explanation about that, but may be because you must specifie an activity to go before you kill the current activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try Overriding onKey method in your activity class

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{   if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) 
    {   finish();
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Isn't have the `onBackPressed()` function override the same thing? When I add that code I get an error that it doesn't override method from the super class

Comment: Add this inside your onBackPressed method: super.onBackPressed();

Comment: And before finish(); method

Comment: I added that and it still makes no difference

Comment: Try to put a toast message or log in onBackPressed() method to check if its actually working.