# Android: take camera picture intent remove confirmation dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

it's possible to disable/remove this photo confirmation dialog:

[image]

I need somehow skip this dialog but I still want use an `Intent`. I found this [android: Take camera picture without "save" / "delete" confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297606/android-take-camera-picture-without-save-delete-confirmation) but I don't want use `SurfaceView` .

Comment: After Lollipop we can do it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/38371325/5079043

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need somehow skip this dialog but I still want use an Intent.

That is not possible.

There are over <strike>8,000</strike> 26,000 Android device models. Across them, there are hundreds of *different* pre-installed camera apps. Additionally, there are hundreds of additional camera apps that users can install from the Play Store or elsewhere. Any one of them could respond to your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request.

The protocol for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not have an option for "do not show any sort of confirmation dialog". Some camera apps will have such a dialog, others will not. A few apps might have some undocumented `Intent` extra for controlling that behavior, but most will not.

Either:

1. Live with the confirmation prompt, where it exists, or
2. Do not delegate this work to a third-party app, but instead use the camera APIs to take a picture yourself (the `SurfaceView` approach that you rejected, though it does not necessarily need `SurfaceView`), or
3. Do not write the app

Answer (score 2):

Use **"android.intent.extra.quickCapture"** in Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture",true);
```

Comment: for me, it is working for Lenovo VIBE device I haven't tested in another device.

Comment: have you found any solution @Rameshkumar?