# Change button text in native camera screen (calling camera via intent)

Tags: android, camera

Users of my app are complaining that buttons when taking image are ambiguous. When I checked to see what they are talking about, I noticed that they are confused by a text of the native camera buttons.

So when I call native camera via `Intent`, camera opens, they take an image, and then on some mobiles the buttons says "OK", some "Save", some "XYZ". This is different for each device. The most confusing part is "Save" text on some Samsung devices because when a user takes an image, it is returned to the app to "do something on it" and then there is another Save button in my app. Users on such devices will press save in the Camera screen, go back to the app, and then complain that "app does not saves the image".

Is there a way to change the text of the native camera buttons? So I can set the text is the same on all cameras and devices.

Comment: My first thought was to get rid of the *confirm* page so that your clients only `Save` once. After a quick search, I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956635/android-take-camera-picture-intent-remove-confirmation-dialog). Looks like it's not a valid approach. My next suggestion would be to implement a simple camera in your app without using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE ` `Intent`. This way you could customize the confirmation screen on your own app.

Comment: @JonZarate Thanks. I think the answer from the link will suit us.