# Using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE asks the user to press OK or RETRY

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a working Android app that uses the MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent to capture a picture. This works but when the user takes a picture it always then asks the user to 'RETRY / OK'. This creates an extra step each time the user takes a picture and is very annoying for my users that take many pictures per-day as part of their job.

Is there a setting or option that turns off this verification step?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581244/how-to-skip-or-avoid-retake-and-review-option-after-captureing-photo-from-came

Comment: You can not handle this behavior. The only possibility is to make your own Camera .